# Calculate expected delivery day based on available days for each day of the week

Tags: powerapps

I need to calculate the next available delivery day for an order, given a set of potential delivery days in the week. When the order is ready, the system should select the closest upcoming delivery day. However, when multiple delivery days are available within the same week, the logic should prioritize the next immediate delivery day rather than defaulting to the first delivery day of the following week.

[front of my app, for this case an order can be delivered on Mondays only, there is an error in the last case where there is no lead time and the order delivery time does not show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUXbg.png)

this code calculates the delivery time between when an order finishes being processed (a task that takes 3 days) and the day it can deliver, first I get a list of days that are selected as available to deliver, then I calculate the lead time based on the day of the week the order is ready and the next delivery day available:

```
Clear(deliveryDaysCollection);
// Add checked days to the collection
ForAll(
    [
        {
            CheckBox: cbxDeliverySun,
            DayNumber: 1
        },
        {
            CheckBox: cbxDeliveryMon,
            DayNumber: 2
        },
        {
            CheckBox: cbxDeliveryTue,
            DayNumber: 3
        },
        {
            CheckBox: cbxDeliveryWed,
            DayNumber: 4
        },
        {
            CheckBox: cbxDeliveryThu,
            DayNumber: 5
        },
        {
            CheckBox: cbxDeliveryFri,
            DayNumber: 6
        },
        {
            CheckBox: cbxDeliverySat,
            DayNumber: 7
        }
    ],
    If(
        CheckBox.Value,
        Collect(
            deliveryDaysCollection,
            {
                DayNumber: DayNumber,
                IsDeliveryDay: CheckBox.Value
            }
        )
    )
);

// Clear or initialize the collection for lead times
Clear(leadTimeCollection);
// Iterate over each day of the week from 4 (Sunday) to 10 (Saturday) because the week starts in 1 (sunday) and it takes 3 days for an order to be processed
ForAll(
    Sequence(
        7,
        4
    ),
    With(
        {currentDay: Value},
        // Calculate the lead time for the current day
        With(
            {
                // Find the next available delivery day or wrap to the first day in the collection if none is found
                nextAvailableDay: LookUp(
                    deliveryDaysCollection,
                    DayNumber >= currentDay,
                    DayNumber
                ),
                firstDeliveryDay: First(deliveryDaysCollection).DayNumber
            },
            Collect(
                leadTimeCollection,
                {
                    week_day: currentDay - 3,
                    lead_time: If(
                        IsBlank(nextAvailableDay),
                        // If no next available day in the week, calculate time until the first delivery day of the next week
                        If(
                            firstDeliveryDay + 7 - currentDay < 0,
                            LookUp(
                    deliveryDaysCollection,
                    DayNumber + 7 >= currentDay,
                    DayNumber - 3
                ),
                            firstDeliveryDay + 7 - currentDay
                        ),
                        // Else calculate time until the next available day this week
                        nextAvailableDay - currentDay
                    )
                }
            )
        )
    )
);
```

for some reason in this case when the only available day to deliver is monday, the last case when an order is created on saturday and it is ready to deliver in tuesday appears without a lead time, the delivery day should be monday of next week (the third monday), instead of setting the next day it returns blank for those cases